# Как использовать вложенный запрос в php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо в запросе сделать запрос по второму параметру:

```
$query="select * from usertbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$res=mysql_query($query);
$num_result=mysql_num_rows($res);
if ($num_result>0) {
    for ($n=0; $n < $num_result; $n++) {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        // тут будет второй запрос по другим параметрам
    }
}
```

Дополнение (перенесено из дополняющего ответа)

```
$query="select * from usertbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$res=mysql_query($query);
$num_result=mysql_num_rows($res);
if ($num_result>0) {
for ($n=0; $n < $num_result; $n++)
{
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
// тут будет второй запрос по другим параметрам
$query2="select * from friends where us_from='$row[username]' or us_to=$row[username]";
$res2=mysql_query($query2);
$row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2);
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in

Comment: А вы уверены что вам действительно нужен второй запрос. В 90% подобных случаев можно обойтись одним запросом который выдаст данные из 2х и более таблиц. Но если все таки нужен, то кто мешает сделать еще один mysql_query

Comment: только вам известно каким будет второй запрос, исходя из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно

Comment: Не используйте mysql_* методы в PHP, они уже давно deprecated. Воспользуйтесь PDO, напишите реализацию по новой, если возникнут проблемы, обновите вопрос. Ваш пример уязвим. В случае если username не обладает достаточной фильтрацией, то можно сделать SQL инъекцию. Используйте bind в PDO.

Comment: Mike прав - если знать, чего конкретно Вызотите добиться, то тут все можно в один запрос сделать.

Comment: Кажется, Вы забыли кавычки около `us_to`. `$query2="select * from friends where us_from='$row[username]' or us_to='$row[username]'";`